# CentOS 7 group permissions not allowing access to folder

Tags: permissions, groups, winbind

I have a CentOS7 box, "box1", domain joined using Winbind + RID method.

I have a folder (NFS mount) @ /shares/share. The permissions are:

```
root@box1:/shares# ls -n /shares/
total 8
drwxrws---  2 0 25022 4096 Jun 15 12:26 share
```

I have multiple AD users trying to access the share. They are all members of the group with GID 25022 "hpc_users".

Some of these users can access the folder and read/write files no problem. Others receive:

```
cd: share: Permission denied
```

This user can access the folder no problem:

```
root@box1:/shares# id user1
uid=27175(user1) gid=10513(domain users) groups=10513(domain users),27175(user1),19009(everyuser),25022(hpc_users),18647(vpn users),1000001(BUILTIN\users)
```

This user cannot:

```
root@box1:/shares# id user2
uid=26153(user2) gid=10513(domain users) groups=10513(domain users),998(shiny),26153(user2),19009(everyuser),25022(hpc_users),18647(vpn users),19710(systems),1000001(BUILTIN\users)
```

and I can't see a valid reason why.

Comment: Out of curiosity, from the point of view of those two users, is the output of `getent group 25022` identical?

Comment: Yes, it is. `hpc_users:x:25022:` for both.